# Trying to parse integer as string (qi::as_wstring)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, boost-spirit

(disclaimer, I am learning boost spirit)

I am trying to parse an expression like this: 
**F( 1 )**

and want to get the 1 as a string ("1" instead of a number (which works with qi::int_)).

I tried something like this (which is wrong, but maybe I am in the right direction), but the resulting string is "**\x1**" instead of just "**1**"

Any insight as to what is needed to parse a number into a string?

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct range_parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, RangeResult(), iso8859_1::space_type>
{
    range_parser() : range_parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using qi::lexeme;
        using qi::int_;
        using iso8859_1::digit;

        number_as_string %= lexeme[ +(int_) ];

        start %=
            qi::lit("F")
            >> '('
            >> number_as_string
            >> ")"
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::wstring(), iso8859_1::space_type> number_as_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, RangeResult(), iso8859_1::space_type> start;
};
```

Comment: can someone edit the title to remove the qi::as_wstring part ? it is not relevent (I think)

Comment: I think you meant to write `+(digit)` (one or more digits) instead of `+(int_)` (one or more integers).  Note that it won't do the same thing as `int_` (no range check, no +/- sign).  If you want to capture the input recognized by int_, you might try using the raw directive: `raw[int_]` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/raw.html

Comment: (got back on the project) Hey @BorisGlick, can you put that as an answer so I can accept this as an answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write `+(digit)` (one or more digits) instead of `+(int_)` (one or more integers). Note that `+(digit)` won't do the same thing as `qi::int_` (no range check, no +/- sign, no limit on the number of digits, accepting inputs like `"000"`, etc).

If you want to capture the input recognized by `qi::int_`, you might try using the raw directive: `raw[int_]` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/raw.html

If necessary, it's possible to save *both* the parsed value and the raw input of the `qi::int_` parser, see here: [qi::rule with inherited attribute as inherited attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634929/qirule-with-inherited-attribute-as-inherited-attribute)

Comment: Thanks. I got my simple things working, but I am still learning the spirit parser.

Comment: You're welcome!  I've been using it for a while, but still at a "learning" stage.